# FontAwesome icons not showing on web url

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-4

I have design a website in HTML and used FontAwesome icon.
When I run the website on localhost,  icon showing fine.
But on url it not working.
Here the url : [Demo](http://qubedns.co.in/codes/design/hotelsr)

here is my Custom CSS:

```
@font-face{
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
        src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=3.2.1');
        src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@#iefix&v=3.2.1') 
        format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff@v=3.2.1') 
        format('woff'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf@v=3.2.1') 
        format('truetype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') 
        format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;
}
```

AND

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

AND

```
.icon-envelope-alt:before{content:"\f003";}
.icon-heart:before{content:"\f004";}
.icon-star:before{content:"\f005";}
.icon-star-empty:before{content:"\f006";}
.icon-user:before{content:"\f007";}
.icon-film:before{content:"\f008";}
.icon-th-large:before{content:"\f009";}
.icon-th:before{content:"\f00a";}
.icon-th-list:before{content:"\f00b";}
.icon-ok:before{content:"\f00c";}
.icon-remove:before{content:"\f00d";}
.icon-zoom-in:before{content:"\f00e";}
.icon-zoom-out:before{content:"\f010";}
.icon-power-off:before,.icon-off:before{content:"\f011";}
.icon-signal:before{content:"\f012";}
```

Anyone help me to fix this.

Thanking you.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is been asked a while , but may this answer help:

This is a server configuration:
you should add this in the web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Full reference [here](https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210926903-HTTP-404-Not-Found-Error-with-woff-or-woff2-Font-Files)

Answer (score 1):

You must include the stylesheet of FontAwesome inside the tag head

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    ...
```

Then, you use in the menu:

```
<span class="icon-angle-down" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></span>
```

The correct version is:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></span>
```

Comment: I have use custom css i.e element on before, that's why I use span like that

Comment: Ah ok, I don't know this particular.
So, the problem is that the files aren't in the correct position in the server

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to find the font on the path: http://qubedns.co.in/codes/design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=3.2.1

This webpage is not available

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Which is the path you are using on your code

```
@font-face{
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
        src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=3.2.1');
        src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot@#iefix&v=3.2.1') 
        format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff@v=3.2.1') 
        format('woff'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf@v=3.2.1') 
        format('truetype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') 
        format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;
}
```

[image]